# A group of cardinality $4$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

Here is how I think I proved that any group of cardinality $4$ is abelian:

***Claim***: a group in which any element $a\ne e$ has order $2$ is abelian

***Proof***: Let $G$ be such a group and let $a,b\ne e$ be in $G$. Since $G$ is a group $ab\in G$ and $(ab)\cdot(ab)=e \text{ because }g^2=e\iff g^{-1}=g$

$\implies aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$

Multiplying by $b$ on the right $aba^{-1}=b$ and since $a,b$ were arbitrary we get the desired result by multiplying by $a$ on the right: $ab=ba$

**Proof that $\#G=4\implies G$ is abelian**:

Let $a\in G\backslash\{e\}$ be an arbitrary element. By Lagrange the order($a$) divides 4. If order$(a)=2$ let's choose $b\ne a$ and $b\ne e$. By the same reasoning either order$(b)=2$ or $4$. If it's $4$ we're done, if it's $2$ let's choose $c\ne e,a,b$. Now if the order of $c$ is $2$ we can use the claim to finish the proof.

If order$(a)=4$ then $G=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic and so isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ so abelian.

Comment: It might be better written as "either $G$ has an element of order $4$ or it doesn't.  Then..."

Comment: As you have written it, you've said that the order of $a$ may be two and therefore $G$ is abelian.  Not so.  That's a statement about a single $a$, not all of them.

Comment: Here's a funny way: suppose you have $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\neq ba$. Then you already have four elements, and there's no room for the identity!

Comment: @SteveD I don't know why but it's not 100% convincing

Comment: It's a valid proof, but it's silly because it gives no insight into *why* the group is abelian. Yours is much better :)

Comment: Your initial claim seems incorrect - Any group of even order must have an element whose order is 2. This does not imply that the group is abelian. For example $S_3$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe I meant every element except the identity has order $2$

Comment: @JohnCataldo, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any appeal to orders of elements, Cauchy's Theorem or Lagrange's or type of group: assume that $G$ has $4$ elements and is not abelian. Then we can find two non-identity elements $a,b$ that do not commute, so $ab \neq ba$. Note that this implies $ab \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Because $G$ is closed under the group operation we must have $G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$. Now $ba$ belongs to this set. Since $a$ and $b$ do not commute $ba \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Hence we must have $ab=ba$, a contradiction. So $G$ is abelian after all.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof of the claim is incorrect: you implicitly assumed commutativity of $a, b$ when wrote $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Instead, observe that
$$abab\ \ =(ab)^2 =e=a^2 b^2 =\ \ aabb$$
And hence $ba=ab$.

Comment: $a=a^{-1},\ b=b^{-1}\implies abab=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$ I'm not assuming anything other than each element is its own inverse

Comment: Ahh.. Ok, then I misunderstood. It's correct that way.