# Group of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that finite groups of prime order is cyclic and abelian, however $4$ is not a prime number so we have to investigate more deeply. For subgroup of group of order $4$ we have two cases by Lagrange Theorem. It is either $2$ or $4$ since if subgroup is H and group of order $4$ is $G$ then $\vert H\vert  \mid \vert G\vert$. Here is my question: In the following we have that

If $H=4$, then we are done since that would mean $G$ has an element of order $4$ thus cyclic $\langle a \rangle = G$. How is that possible? I mean how subgroups order related to the elements order. Do we use the theorem saying: "$\langle a \rangle$ is of order m if and only if $o(a)=m$"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If an element of order $4$ exists, the group generated by it has size $4$  , but is also a subset of a set of size $4$ ($G$), so must be the set itself.

Comment: Or more clear question: In a group of order 4 do we have only two possibilities (2, 4) for order of an element of a group? And if it is 2 then we will have $a^2=b^2=c^2=e$ otherwise $a^4=e$

Comment: Why do not we have an element of order 3 ?

Comment: If $o(a)=3$, $\langle a \rangle$ has size $3$ and is a subgroup but $3$ does not divide $4$, contradicting Lagrange.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I am looking for

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: You might want to read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925461/a-group-of-cardinality-4-is-abelian